# Does find support OR in its regexes?

Tags: find, regular-expression

For example, I want to find all files in a directory that end in 'm' or 'sh'. The following works correctly:

```
find . -regex '.*.m' -o -regex '.*.sh'
```

But this fails:

```
find . -regex '.*.(m|sh)'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just escaping hell:

```
find . -regex '.*.\(m\|sh\)
```

appears to work. I don't think there's much consensus whether regexp special chars need to be escaped or need to be unescaped between different tools.

Comment: find(1) uses POSIX Basic regular expressions by default (and so does grep). Use the `-E` switch (BSD) or the `-regextype posix-extended` (GNU) to switch to the modern extended flavour

Comment: Also see the final paragraph of re_format(7) for the differences between BRE and ERE: http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?re_format+7+NetBSD-current